# Open Graph Action POST fails when called thru a google app engine based unpaid instance

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, urllib2, facebook-opengraph

urlopen fails with a 500 code and '{"error_code":1,"error_msg":"An unknown error occurred"}' error from Facebook when posting an Open Graph Action. I can get the code to work with other posts (e.g. posting a comment on a status using the graph API works fine). I can also get this action-post to work using curl. So this seems like a urllib2.urlopen issue when posting a form-data with a URL as one of the values.

Graph api post that works with curl :

```
curl -F 'access_token=nnnnnn' -F 'object=https://abc.com/123' \
'https://graph.facebook.com/me/namespace:action' -k
```

Same Graph api post thru urllib2 which gives the error :

```
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request, URLError

request = Request (url='http://graph.facebook.com/me/namespace:action';, 
                   data = urllib.urlencode(
                            {'object':'https://abc.com/123',
                             'access_token':'nnnnnnnn'
                            }, 
                   headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
          ) 
response = urlopen (request)
```

What could I be doing wrong ? (I am new to urllib2.urlopen. Btw, I originally tried urlfetch.fetch thru the urlfetch python module. That did not work either). I am using this thru goole app engine.

Comment: what error does it give?

Comment: urlopen fails with a 500 code and content of '{"error_code":1,"error_msg":"An unknown error occurred"}'. I think this is coming back from Facebook's graph url on the post. It is probably not able to decode the form data or something of that sort. I am wondering if there is anybody who has done a facebook open graph 'action' posts thru Python. Would love to see bits of the code on how the form data is encoded for the urlopen(or any other function) call. Btw, I have also tried using urlfetch.fetch call with a POST method and that did not work either..

Answer (score 1):

After a fair amount of digging/trial-error, finally managed to solve this.

This is not an issue with urllib urlopen, but more of a Google App Engine nuance where when an action post on an open Graph URL is called - it causes Facebook to trigger a 'get' on the Object URL (synchronously).

So essentially the get is being called on app engine app while an active instance is already calling the FB graph URL. I am currently using an **unpaid instance** and this is causing an unexpected behavior such that FB to fails the OG post (I see the get on the logs going thru successfully, while the active post, so not sure what causes FB to fail - anybody with an insight, please share).

I got around this by 'taskqueue'ing urlopen/OG-action-post - and when this is called the second time (FB apparently caches the object the first time) it succeeds.

If anybody needs more details, get in touch and am more than happy to save you all the time and pain that I have already gone thru..

Comment: I am assuming that when paid app on google engine will allow for multiple parallel or concurrent requests to succeed and this problem should not happen. Although I have not tested/confirmed. Anybody has this working - please can you share your experience/views. Thanks.